# Validation rule, text input field and picklist value

Tags: validation-rule, administration

I'm trying to write the validation rule that follow this condition.

> `Date_CheckIn__c` should not be empty and `Status` <> `In Progress` or `Closed`

```
AND(
NOT(ISBLANK( Date_CheckIn__c )),
OR(
ISPICKVAL( Status__c , "In Progress"),
ISPICKVAL( Status__c , "Closed")
),
)
```

The above formula error out:

> Error: Syntax error. Found ')'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nick Kahn Please check the below formula, you have added an extra ',' after ')'  `ISPICKVAL( Status__c , "Closed"))`

```
AND(
NOT(ISBLANK( Date_CheckIn__c )),
OR(
ISPICKVAL( Status__c , "In Progress"),
ISPICKVAL( Status__c , "Closed")
))
```

Comment: Error is gone but the logic does not work and yes my validation is active

Comment: @NickKahn Can you check now? AND(
NOT(ISBLANK( Date_CheckIn__c )),
OR(
NOT(ISPICKVAL( Status__c , "In Progress"),
NOT(ISPICKVAL( Status__c , "Closed")
))

Comment: still does not work, it does not fire the validation rule so the logic should be `Date_CheckIn__c should not be empty and Status CANNOT be "In Progress" or "Closed"`

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra comma at the end of you formula. After the second to last parenthesis.

Comment: Error is gone but the logic does not work and yes my validation is active

Comment: From reading your message, it looks like you want `ISBLANK( Date_CheckIn__c )` instead of `NOT(ISBLANK( Date_CheckIn__c ))`.